# How to create lists in a PDF using Prawn, from HTML UL and OL HTML tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pdf, html-lists, prawn

I'm using [Prawn](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn) to generate my PDF files from a HTML source. This HTML contains only some basic formatting, such as bold, italic, underlines, ordered and unordered lists. For the first three, Prawn will take care of using `:inline_format => true` in the `text` command.

How do I tell Prawn to understand `ul`and `ol` tags and turn them into lists in the PDF file? I understand I should use some helper. Anyone has faced this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As such, Prawn does not provide an in-built HTML parse and hence, it won't know what the `ul` and `li` tags mean. [Prawn's Text-box](http://rdoc.info/github/sandal/prawn/master/Prawn/Text/Box) might be the closest option.

EDIT:

--

To this end, here is a small, feasible implementation:

Say the html string is `<ul><li>First line</li><li>Second line</li></ul>`

Using any Ruby HTML parser, you can parse the lines. Here I've used Nokogiri.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'prawn'

Prawn::Document.generate "result.pdf" do |pdf|
  Nokogiri::HTML("html_string_above").xpath('//li').each do |node|
    pdf.text_box "#{node.inner_html}"
  end
end
```

--

It would be a lot easier to use a html to pdf conversion gems to achieve this. Take a look at [WickedPDF](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) project.

Comment: Thanks Kashyap!! Really interesting project. Still, I think I'd rather stick to Prawn since it's a pure-ruby library and frees us from external dependencies such as wkhtmltopdf. Our only formatting needs are uls and ols so I'd rather solve it with a helper.

Comment: Understood. I myself prefer prawn over wkhtmltopdf based options :) Edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Kashyap! I also answered with my own attempt for the sake of completion, but I believe your answer is more consistent so I mark it as answered.

Comment: I need your help, would you mind taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041641/create-a-table-in-prawn-by-its-html-representation ?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up myself building a tiny helper, which might not be very clean but seems to work quite well with tidy HTML

```
def parse_lists(body)
  # add a bullet for each line in a list.
  body = body.gsub(/<li>/, "<li>#{Prawn::Text::NBSP * 3}<font size='20'>  •  </font>")
  # add a line break for any list element, since li, ol and ul will be later removed.
  body.gsub(/<\/ul>/, "</ul><br>").gsub(/<\/li>/, "</li><br>").gsub(/<\/ol>/, "</ol><br>")
end
```

Which I later use along with some HTML sanitizing and called from a `text parse_lists(body), :inline_format => true` Prawn command.

I'm marking Kashyap's answer as correct since it's probably way more consistent, but also leaving this working snipper in case it helps others.

Answer (score 1):

A good approach is providing a method for **pre-processing** the HTML string using Nokogiri, leaving only basics tags in the text that Prawn could manage with "inline_format" option:

```
def self.render_html_text(instr)
   # Replacing <p> tag
   outstr = instr.gsub('<p>',"\n")
   outstr.gsub!('</p>',"\n")
   # Replacing <ul> & <li> tags
   doc = Nokogiri::HTML(outstr)
   doc.search('//ul').each do |ul|
     content = Nokogiri::HTML(ul.inner_html).xpath('//li').map{|n| "• #{n.inner_html}\n"}.join
     ul.replace(content)
   end
   #removing some <html><body> tags inserted by Nokogiri
   doc.at_xpath('//body').inner_html
end
```